# Wondering why I'm getting the error "use of an undeclared identifier"

Tags: c, cs50

```
   // TODO: Calculate number of years until we reach threshold
   { 
    int years;
    while (ending_size>=starting_size)
    starting_size = starting_size + (starting_size/3) - (starting_size/4);
    years++;
    }
            {// TODO: Print number of years
            printf("Years: %i\n", years);
            }
}
```

When I run my code, it says "use of undeclared identifier "years", and I think it might be due to the way that I formatted my code. Thanks

Comment: The code you show can't be compiled.  Please read about how to create an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 — or MRE or whatever name SO now uses)
or an
SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)).
The variable `years` that you show declared between `{` and `}` is not accessible outside that block of code.  That's why the second block says that `years` is undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have `{` … `}` around the code where years is declared. I think that's your problem. The `{` and `}` limit its scope.